# UITableViewCell in Edit mode in iOS

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I am working on screen where user will be available to remove items to by swipe left (default tableView behavior).

When user opens that screen I want to show him that he is availabe to remove items to swipe. So, I want to show "Delete button" in the first cell for 2 seconds and when hide it. How can I do it? I can not find any information how to manage this Mode programmaticaly

Can it be done with HitTest?

Comment: Why do you want to point to a standard behavior?

Comment: to make sure that users will understand how to remove items...because my cells are not a standard

Comment: Where do you want the button?
In the left edge or the right edge? I'd actually suggest an image instead of a button